# Testing a polynomial is irreducible.

Tags: ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

This question may be easy but I am unable to fix it.

How is the polynomial $f(x,y)=x^2-2y^2$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R= \mathbb{Q}[y].$ Note that $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ is canonically isomorphic to $R[x] = (\mathbb{Q}[y])[x],$ and that $R$ is a unique factorization domain.

You want to show $x^2 - 2y^2$ is irreducible in $R[x].$ The coefficients of this polynomial are $1$ and $-2y^2.$ Since the greatest common divisor of the coefficients is $1,$ the polynomial is primitive and Gauss's lemma applies. This states that $x^2-2y^2$ is irreducible in $R[x]$ if and only if it is irreducible in $(\text{Frac}(R))[x],$ where $\text{Frac}(R)$ is the field of fractions of $R.$

A quadratic polynomial with coefficients in a field is reducible if and only if it has a root, so your polynomial is reducible in $(\text{Frac}(R))[x]$  if and only if there is a rational function $g(y)\in \mathbb{Q}(y)$ such that $g(y)^2 = 2y^2.$

If there is such a $g,$ write it as $g(y) = \dfrac{a(y)}{b(y)}$ where $a(y),b(y)\in \mathbb{Q}[y]$ and have no common factors. Then we have the following equality in the ring $\mathbb{Q}[y]$ : $$ a(y)^2 = 2y^2 b(y)^2.$$

The coefficients of $a$ and $b$ are rational numbers. If we clear denominators on both sides we get an equality of the form $$ \tilde{a}(y)^2 = 2 y^2 \tilde{b}(y)^2$$ where $\tilde{a},\tilde{b}\in \mathbb{Z}[y],$ which is a UFD. Now note that the power of $2$ in the prime factorization of the left hand side is even, while on the right it is odd. Hence we have a contradiction and so such $g(y)$ exists. Therefore $f$ is irreducible in $(\text{Frac}(R))[x],$ and so $x^2-2y^2$ is irreducible in $R[x] = \mathbb{Q}[x,y].$

Comment: What do you mean by canonically isomorphic? Could you please provide the explicit map?

Comment: Try the following exercise: For any commutative ring $R$ and indeterminates $x$ and $y,$ we have $(R[x])[y] = R[x,y].$ That is, adjoining indeterminates after each other is the same as adjoining them at the same time. It is clear that, as sets, $(R[x])[y] \subseteq R[x,y]$. Conversely, show that you can write any polynomial in $R[x,y]$ as a polynomial in $y$ with coefficients in $R[x]$ to get $R[x,y]\subseteq (R[x])[y].$ After you see the underlying sets are equal, also verify their ring operations are the same.

Comment: Thanks! I got it what you are saying.

If you know on the top of your head, do you mind providing reference of this fact, which you used above:

"A quadratic polynomial is reducible if and only if it has a root."

Comment: @Algebra Sorry, your question just made me realize a mistake in my proof. "A quadratic polynomial is reducible if and only if it has a root" is true if the coefficient ring is a field (try to prove this yourself), but not generally. For example, $2x^2+2 \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is reducible because it is equal to $2 \cdot (x^2+1)$ where $2$ and $x^2+1$ are irreducible elements of $\mathbb{Z}[x].$ To fix my proof I'll need to appeal to Gauss's lemma, but it's not much harder. See my edit in a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, your statement "A quadratic polynomial is reducible if and only if it has a root" is true only if the coefficients are coming from a field.

Comment: @Algebra See my edit.

Comment: I think it should be okay now. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean, $Frac(R)=\mathbb{Q}(y)$?

Comment: @Algebra Yes, if $R = \mathbb{Q}[y]$ then its field of fractions if $\mathbb{Q}(y).$

Answer (score 1):

If $x^2 - 2y^2 = (ax + by)(cx + dy)$ for $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z[x,y]}$, then:

$ac = 1$, $ad + bc = 0$, and $bd = -2$. So: $b = 2, d = -1$ or $b = -2, d = 1$, or $b = -1, d = 2$, and $b = 1, d = -2$. But $a = c = 1$ or $a = c = -1$. Either of these yields:
$b + d = 0$, but this can't happen. So you get the irreducibility of $f(x,y)$ over $\mathbb{Z[x,y]}$, but this implies irreducibility over $\mathbb{Q[x,y]}$

Comment: Why $b+d=0$ can't happen?

Comment: @Algebra: because bd = -2. So b = -2 , d = 1, etc... you add them ...

Comment: The polynomial is in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ but you are considering in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$, why?